# Hide IOS keyboard without UITapGestureReconize?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I need to hide the keyboard (UITextFiled) when I press a botton off the keyboard, as Cancel, without altering a TableView, because with that I do a search string.

It has not worked for me UITapGestureRecognizer 
 because then not recognize when selecting a cell.

```
[textfield resignFirstReponder]
```

Do not achieve as it is an action outside the keyboard or TextField .??

Is Valid in Action Button

```
[self textFieldShouldClear:self.textField];
```

With

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) method of `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [textfield resignFirstReponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO on your gesture recognizer if you want it to pass touches to the rest of your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the keyboard it hide when you scroll the tableview you could do...

```
myTableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your viewController to be a TextFieldDelegate, keep a reference to activeTextField by setting it in textFieldDidBeginEditing

In the cancel function, call [activeTextField resignFirstResponder]